# running express.js app in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, hosting, iis-express, iisnode

I would like to run node.js with asp.net mvc for performing socket.io operations.

i've successfully included the node.js in asp.net mvc as described in [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/26/using-node-js-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application-with-iisnode.aspx)

my problem is how to run express.js in asp.net mvc,

i've performed the url rewritting in Global.asax.cs file like

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get current path
            string CurrentPath = Request.Path.ToLower();
  if (CurrentPath.StartsWith("/node"))
            { HttpContext MyContext = HttpContext.Current;
                MyContext.RewritePath("/Node/index.js/");
            }
}

so in the url **http:localhost:1234/node** should redirect me to the index.js file in Node folder

it is all working well but,
when i start coading express.js server in index.js like

var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.get('/node/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(' welcome to express ');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);

I got error saying **Cannot GET /Node/index.js/**

where am i missing? please guide me how to write express.js coading in asp.net mvc

Iam running this application in windows 7 32 bit system with IIS 8.0 express , and installed node versions are
iisnode.js - iisnode-full-iis7-v0.2.3-x86
node.js - node-v0.8.19-x86

Thank you.

Comment: Since you are already in ASP.NET MVC, any reason you are not using SignalR? http://signalr.net/

Comment: Because i want to perform io chat based applications so i choose node.js

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a web.config entry for iisnode handling index.js?

iisnode is not set up as a .js handler by default, since there is far more client-side javascript than server-side javascript, so you need to explicitly turn on iisnode as a handler for that file.